# PDO connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason I am having a really difficult time getting my PDO connection to work. I am entering the correct host, username and password that has allowed me to get into the same database, but other tables.

I have my connection setup like the following, other than the actual username, password and db entered in. I have checked it 10x and it is the correct information.

The latest error I have recieved in the error reporting file is this:

[25-Oct-2016 13:22:07 America/Chicago] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$servernameCon' (T_VARIABLE)

I have changed localhost to the Dedicated IP Address, which I do not have to do for any other connection on my site, and even doing this still doesn't help.

I am at a loss for what I am doing wrong. Does anyone see anything I am missing?

```
    $servernameCon = 'localhost';
    $usernameCon = ' ';
    $passwordCon = ' ';

    $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servernameCon.';dbname= ', $usernameCon, $passwordCon);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Before $servernameCon:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        if(Input::exists()) {
            $validate = new Validate();
            $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                'firstname' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 50
                ),
                'lastname' => array (
                    'required' => true,
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 50
                ),
                'email' => array (
                    'required' => true,
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 50
                ),
                'phone' => array (
                    'required' => true,
                    'min' => 7,
                    'max' => 12
                ),
                'network' => array (
                    'required' => true
                ),
                'birthday' => array (
                    'required' => true
                ),
                'username' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'min' => 4,
                    'max' => 20,
                    'unique' => 'users'
                ),
                'password' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'min' => 6
                ),
                'password_again' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'matches' => 'password'
                )

            ));
            if($validation->passed()) {
                $user = new User();

                $salt = Hash::salt(32);

                try {

                    $user->create(array(
                        'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                        'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                        'email' => Input::get('email'),
                        'phone' => Input::get('phone'),
                        'network' => Input::get('network'),
                        'birthday' => Input::get('birthday'),
                        'username' => Input::get('username'),
                        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                        'salt' => $salt,
                        'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'group' => 1
                    ));

                    ($user->lastId);

                    //Add user to posts table
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        $id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
                        $user_id = $user->lastId;
                        $posts = 0;
                        $conversations = 0;
```

Comment: What is before line `$servernameCon = 'localhost';`?

Comment: as per the gazillions of dupes on this site: you forgot something on an EARLIER line, and the line number in your error is merely the first place where that missing something caused a parse error.

Comment: Is php_pdo_sql extension enabled in php.ini?

Comment: I added what was before the servernamecon variable.

Comment: I didn't forget anything on an earlier line, nor am I a dupe, get over yourself. 

How can I check it see if it is enabled?

Comment: Anyone?? I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just for your information: stack overflow is not a support forum. Here we can answer certain questions, like "how to do something". While questions "why my code doesn't work" are off topic. But yeah, sometimes you get that forum in the comments. Ok, did you fix your syntax error?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know it isn't and I appreciate any help I receive from here. No, I didn't fix the syntax because I do not see where any syntax is wrong.